# Got 401 error when deploy jhipster monolithic app in production profile

Tags: angular, jwt, jhipster

I generated a jhipster monolithic app with V4.13.0
jhipster options below:

```
>Monolithic 
> Do not use Jhipster Registry
> authentication (stateless, with a token)
> MySQL in production, H2 in-memory in development
> ehcache
> Gradle
> Angular 5
> Do not enable SASS
> Do not enable i18n
> No testing frameworks
> Do not install other generators
```

I did not modify application-prod.yml except jdbc content;
and my angular env is

```
Angular CLI: 1.6.0
Node: 9.3.0
OS: linux x64
Angular: 5.1.0
```

package following jh guide

```
./gradlew  -Pprod clean bootRepackage
```

and run by

```
build/libs/xx-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war 
----------------------------------------------------------
    Application 'xx' is running! Access URLs:
    Local:      http://localhost:8080
    External:   http://127.0.0.1:8080
    Profile(s):     [prod]
----------------------------------------------------------
```

but when I request by browser by http://localhost:8080
it got

```
o.z.p.spring.web.advice.AdviceTrait      : Unauthorized: Full authentication is required to access this resource
```

browser side error is:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:8080/api/account
Request Method:GET
Status Code:401 Unauthorized
Remote Address:[::1]:8080
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

Thanks advance for anyone and any help!

Comment: You should use a LTS version of node as recommended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I misunderstood your issue, it's the expected behavior: you must first authenticate against /api/authenticate to get a token and then use it to access /api/account